# Error 500 on connecting to self-hosted Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm running a Gitlab hosted on a server. When I do `git clone http://mydomainname.com/muz/test.git` it gives the following error:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://mydomainname.com/muz/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

I've tried several things, including opening all ports, increasing RAM and swap size to 1+3 GB respectively. Are there any other things I should look at?

Comment: Probably an issue with your configuration. Too vague to help troubleshoot here though.

Comment: @MattSchuchard When you say configuration, do you mean something from this? https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was an error that happened because we isntalled it through a Bitnami image. We installed Omnibus later and it worked.